# oracle 12c query is slow

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, subquery, oracle12c

below code works well in 11g BUT only in 12c works so slow (over 10 sec).

```
SELECT * FROM DMProgValue_00001
  WHERE 1=1
  AND ProgressOID IN ( 
    SELECT P.OID FROM (
      SELECT OID FROM (
        SELECT A.OID, ROWNUM as seqNum FROM (
            SELECT OID FROM DMProgress_00001 WHERE 1=1
            AND Project = 'Q539'
            ORDER BY actCode
        ) A
        WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
    ) WHERE seqNum > 20
  ) P
);


Plan hash value: 763232015

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                   |     1 |   189 |   171   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                   |                   |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL       | DMPROGVALUE_00001 |     1 |   189 |    68   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   VIEW                    |                   |    20 |   800 |   103   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    COUNT STOPKEY          |                   |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |     VIEW                  |                   |  2916 | 78732 |   103   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|                   |  2916 |   130K|   103   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DMPROGRESS_00001  |  2916 |   130K|   102   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM  (SELECT "A"."OID" "OID",ROWNUM "SEQNUM" FROM  
              (SELECT "OID" "OID" FROM "DMPROGRESS_00001" "DMPROGRESS_00001" WHERE 
              "PHASE"='Construction' AND "PROJECT"='Q539' ORDER BY "ACTCODE") "A" WHERE ROWNUM<=40) 
              "from$_subquery$_003" WHERE "SEQNUM">20 AND "OID"=:B1))
   3 - filter("SEQNUM">20 AND "OID"=:B1)
   4 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   6 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   7 - filter("PHASE"='Construction' AND "PROJECT"='Q539')

DMProgress_0001 stats
NUM_ROW : 10385
BLOCKS : 370
AVG_ROW_LEN : 176
SMAPLE_SIZE : 8263


DMProgvalue_0001 stats
NUM_ROW : 15703
BLOCKS : 244
AVG_ROW_LEN : 49
SMAPLE_SIZE : 5033
```

It's only 10k rows and Indexs are well made ( I can tell because of 11g experience). I know some detour way to make fast ( below code - 0.001 sec) BUT I want to know real problem and fix it.

I cannot understand it only has one sub query and 10k rows for each table. Not just compared to 11g, There is no way that this query takes over 10 sec.

```
SELECT * FROM DMProgValue_00001 V,
  (SELECT OID FROM (
        SELECT A.OID, ROWNUM as seqNum FROM (
            SELECT OID FROM DMProgress_00001 WHERE 1=1
            AND Project = 'Q539'
            ORDER BY actCode
        ) A
        WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
    ) WHERE seqNum > 20
  ) P
  WHERE 1=1
  AND V.ProgressOID = P.OID;
```

---

```
added 11g similar query plan
Plan hash value: 3049049852

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                   |     9 |   684 |    49   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI      |                   |     9 |   684 |    49   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW                     | VW_NSO_1          |     3 |    81 |    35   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    VIEW                    |                   |     3 |    75 |    35   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     COUNT STOPKEY          |                   |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      VIEW                  |                   |     3 |    36 |    35   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|                   |     3 |   144 |    35   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DMPROGRESS_00037  |     3 |   144 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL        | DMPROGVALUE_00037 |  5106 |   244K|    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("PROGRESSOID"="OID")
   3 - filter("SEQNUM">20)
   4 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   6 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   7 - filter("DISPLINE"='Q340' AND "PHASE"='Procurement' AND "PROJECT"='Moho')
```

oracle 11g automatically change the query as Hash join BUT 12c does not. I think this is point. They are same structure.

Comment: i see two different query, am i right? you are using IN in the first query, but   you are using JOIN in the second. I think that makes the difference :)

Comment: What's the explain plan for the 11g version? Also, are all the stats up to date on the 12c db?

Comment: My guess is  in the 11g's explain plan will be an index

Comment: read post. last query is for my detour solution. I KNOW query might be little silly but works well any other dbms. I added 11g query plan

Comment: table name and contents are little different but I can tell they are same structure and contents are not problem.

Comment: Try: `CREATE INDEX some_name ON DMProgress_00001( Project, ActCode )`

Comment: subquery (using DMProgress_ table) is fast enough BUT when It meet 'IN', it's getting slower. I already added index on MdProgValue_ table.